# If Username == Anton, then do something

Tags: c#

how can i do so if my username are Anton, then show, if not then dont show.

I already tried the following thing.

```
 if(Session["username"] == "Anton")
 {
   btnNew.Visible = true;
 }
 else
 {
   btnNew.Visible = false;
 }
```

Comment: `Session["username"].ToString()`

Comment: in addition to Farhad's comment check for `null` as well like `Session["username"] != null && Session["username"] == "Anton"`, It will save you from Null Reference Exception.

Comment: or `!IsNullOrEmpty` is probably better..

Comment: @MethodMan, `IsNullOrEmpty` is for strings, you can't use that with `Session["key"]` since that will return *a* `object`

Comment: why not.. I do it all the time and get no issues when casting and or using `.ToString()`

Comment: @MethodMan, casting, *yes*, `ToString`, **no**, this `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["username"].ToString())` will throw a NRE if the key "username" doesn't exist in Session. **Also casting only works**, if the value is either `null` or a string. If it holds a non string value, you will get exception again.

Comment: well assuming that the `OP` does not Initialize the Session object in the `OnSessionStart` for example then you are correct.. but if they do.. then what I have provided will protect against the `NRE` actually I just tested your theory @Habib and you are incorrect.. the `IsNullOrEmpty` handles exactly what I expected and it will not generate a `NRE` try it and you will see `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["username"].ToString())` I am not using that thus my code example will not fail what you stated will fail..

Comment: @MethodMan, are you saying this `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["username"].ToString())` doesn't throw an exception if "username" has never been set  or `string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["username"])` ?

Comment: I just tested my code example making up a unassigned session variable in a Page_Load event in my current web app and it does not fail try it and you will see I tried it with if(string.IsNullOrEmpty...... before commenting on something I think that it's best you also try out in regards to exactly what I have written.. I would not post something that I have not first tested @Habib

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70322/discussion-between-habib-and-methodman).

Comment: @Habib try this code out using the negated and non-negated and you will see what I am talking about 
            `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["myTest"]))
            {

            }`

Comment: @Habib I always say that if you learn something new than it's not a wasted  day..respectfully speaking. cheers

Comment: btw @Habib I am heading to Toronto in a Month perhaps we can do Coffee and knock heads over .NET have a good one

Comment: @MethodMan, I think, I wasn't clear enough in my comments, my apologies.  This `(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["myTest"]))` would never throw an exception, if "myTest` doesn't exists or `"myTest"` contains something that is convertible to string. But just try one thing. Just before this line have `Session["myTest"] = 1;`, now this line will throw an exception in casting. Not a NRE, but unable to cast exception. And my apologies again if I sounded rude.

Comment: @MethodMan, sure, but next month I am coming to US, probably till Stillwater, OK.

Comment: @Habib  you didn't sound rude at all ... I was referencing in the context of what the `OP` has provided ...no harm no foul.. you're good.

Comment: and yes is `Session["myTest"] = 1` would fail but if  `Session["myTest"] = 1.ToString()` would not.. it's all good.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["username"]) && (string)Session["username"] == "Anton")
 {
   btnNew.Visible = true;
 }
 else
 {
   btnNew.Visible = false;
 }
```